# Multiplication in Python not working

Tags: python-3.x, math

I have the bizarre error in python 3.4 where multiplication does not work!

This is my code:

```
timerlenth = input('Please enter the amount of minute: ')
int(timerlenth)
timersec = (timerlenth*60)
print (timersec)
```

Here is a photo of the result:

[image: The code multiplies the input by 60 and I get a result for 1111111...]

I am practically clueless on trying to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` function returns a string. Therefore the variable `timerlenth` stores a string. Next line, `int(timerlenth)` converts this variable to integer, but does nothing with the result, leaving the `timerlenth` as the same string it used to be. Python has this functionality where `[string]*x` will repeat the string `x` times and that's what you see in the output.

To get actual multiplication, you'll have to store the value of `int(timerlenth)` to a variable, preferably a new one (good programming practice) and use the new value with multiplication operation.

Answer (score 0):

`timerlenth` is a string, so the `*` operator just concatinates it 60 times instead of multiplying it. This caused by your misuse of `int` - it doesn't change the passed argument, it returns an integer value for it, which you then lose by not assigning it anywhere. Just reassign it to `timerlenth` and you should be fine:

```
timerlenth = int(timerlenth)
```